# type safety: Potential heap pollution via varags parameter element

Tags: java

Necesito hacer lo siguiente:

Realiza una interfaz genérica que contenga dos métodos:

```
T primerContenido();
T ultimoContenido();
```

Realiza una clase Almacen que contenga una lista de cajas. Dicha clase debe implementar esta inferfaz. Los métodos devolverán el contenido de la primera caja y el contenido de la última caja respectivamente.

Por ahora tengo:

```java
package exercise2;

public interface GetElement<T> {
    T primerContenido();
    T ultimoContenido();
}
```

```java
package exercise2;

public class Caja<T> {

    private T element;

    public Caja(T element) {
        this.element = element;
    }

    public T getElement() {
        return element;
    }

    public void setElement(T element) {
        this.element = element;
    }
}

}
```

```java
package exercise2;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Almacen<T> {

    ArrayList<Caja<T>> stock = new ArrayList<Caja<T>>();

    public Almacen(T... element) {
        for(T e : element) {
            stock.add(new Caja<T>(e));

        }
    }
}
```

En esta parte del código `public Almacen(T... element)` el editor me muestra la advertencia del título y no entiendo a qué se refiere o cómo solucionarlo.

> type safety: Potential heap pollution via varags parameter element

¿Alguien me puede echar una mano?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No es una cuestión trivial, así que intentaré explicarla en detalle:

Java admite métodos con número variable de parámetros, pero todos han de ser del mismo tipo, por ejemplo:

```
class Test {
    void metodo(int... p) {
        //algo de código
    }
}
```

El uso de un número variable de parámetros se llama *varargs* (de *variable arguments*). Dentro de este método **p es un array** (no una List) de `int`, por lo que se puede llamar de dos maneras:

```
miTest.metodo(1,2,3,4);
```

o también así:

```
int[] numeros = { 1,2,3,4});
miTest.metodo(numeros);
```

En tu caso has declarado el parámetro *varargs* usando un tipo genérico.
El problema es que los **arrays no admiten genéricos** como una lista, así que tras compilar, el método queda como:

```
class Test {
    void metodo(Object[] p) {
        //algo de código
    }
}
```

Además `Integer[]` extiende `Object[]`, pero no al revés, no se puede transformar un `Object[]` a `Integer[]` (aunque en cada posición guardes un Integer)

Explicado esto, mira este nuevo ejemplo:

```
class Test2 {
    <T> T[] metodo1(T... things) {
        return things;
    }
    <T> T[] metodo2(T thing) {
        return metodo1(thing);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test2 t = new Test2();
        Integer[] r = t.metodo2(3);
    }
}
```

En teoría este código debería funcionar, no da errores de compilación, pero lanza warnings. Pero cuando lo ejecutas obtienes lo siguiente:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Integer;    at
>   functional.Test2.main(Test2.java:13)

¿Qué ha pasado? Bueno, veamos el fichero Test2.class ["descompilado"](http://www.javadecompilers.com/):

```
class Test2 { Test2() {}

  <T> T[] metodo1(T... things) { return things; }

  <T> T[] metodo2(T thing) {
    return metodo1(new Object[] { thing });
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Test2 t = new Test2();
    Integer[] r = (Integer[])t.metodo2(Integer.valueOf(3));
  }
}
```

Como vemos, se ha tenido que transformar el `int` a `Integer` para trabajar con genéricos (no se admiten primitivas).
Tras esto, se ha creado un array de `Object` con este `Integer`, lo que es correcto porque `Integer` sí extiende de `Object`... pero cuando se ha intentado *castear* a `Integer[]`, no se ha podido porque un `Object[] != Integer[]`.

Como puedes ver, es un caso muy extraño que no se te va a dar a menudo, así que puedes ignorarlo. Si te molesta el warning, puedes eliminarlo con la anotación [`@SafeVarargs`](https://www.baeldung.com/java-safevarargs), que es una forma de decirle al compilador "sé lo que estoy haciendo".

O directamente, puedes evitar el uso de genéricos en varargs..